# When an electron collides with the detector in the double slit experiment, what is its momentum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

Let's assume we have a standard double-slit experiment, just for illustration's sake.

When an electron collides with the detector, is its momentum parallel to the emitter's output, or is it something else?

I know that the uncertainty principle forbids us from knowing too much about the momentum when we know the position, so let's assume we have a magic detector that will only give us the momenta and not the positions. This magic detector can detect the momentum of a single electron.

If we shot one electron through this apparatus at a time, what would we see (on average)? I say on average, because there's a non-zero chance that the electron lines up with the emitter by chance. We should still be able to see the standard deviation of the momenta; if it's tight, then the momenta line up with the emitter, otherwise, it's relative to something else.

I'll admit this question may be nonsense, but to my knowledge, the only limitations to this are engineering ones (due to the magic detector), not physical limitations. If this experiment is nonsense due to a physical limitation that I've misunderstood, I'd like to know why.